# How to print DD/MM/YYYY in js

Tags: javascript

```
// having all variables in a an object.
let student = "";
    student = {
  studentName: fn + ',' + ln.toUpperCase(),
  **date : date.toLocaleDateString(),**
  gender : gender,
  country : country,
  address : address,
  email : email,
};
```

this is a part of the code.
When i run it. it prints in mm/dd/yyyy in the html
how to make it print dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try passing 'en-GB' as a parameter?
From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

> In basic use without specifying a locale, a formatted string in the default locale and with default options is returned.

```js
let date = new Date();
console.log('en-GB format:', date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
console.log('en-US format:', date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
```

Comment: thank you very much. new to js and didnt know about 'en-GB'